# Multiple versions of R on Ubuntu, with CRAN binaries

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, debian, cran

RStudio has made packages for multiple versions of R available and described how to install them here: https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/ .  That seems to work pretty well for installing multiple versions of R on the same box - this is something we like in my organization for testing.

Separately, Ubuntu (Debian, really [Dirk Eddelbuettel, really]) has created system packages for CRAN packages, which is fantastic for rapid installation, getting system dependencies right, etc.: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html

Is there a way to have both benefits at once?  In other words, install several versions of the Ubuntu R packages on a single system, and be able to install CRAN packages by using `apt` to install them as system packages, rather than using `install.packages()` in R?

The Ubuntu installation method described at the page above leads me to believe that the versions of R are mutually exclusive, because you set the version by choosing a corresponding `apt` repository, and the packages themselves (probably?) conflict across versions.  Is this correct?

Comment: Tangential comment, not resolving your question: I've found the two biggest benefits of using `apt` for R's packages are (1) reproducibility, they're all stable and not-quickly-changing; and (2) fast, binary-package installation. In the past, it's been otherwise cumbersome to install bigger packages in linux because of the difficulty in maintaining binary packages for so many linux distros. However, with RStudio's [public package manager](https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/07/01/announcing-public-package-manager/), they now provide binary packages for most distros, negating that "disadvantage".

Comment: And yes, I agree that same-named (meaning: same R package, same package version, for a different version of R) `.deb` packages will likely conflict. If the PPAs shifted to include the R major and minor (but not necessarily patch) versions in the package name, that would go a long way to enable what you're asking. But that isn't the case (afaict). (Yes. @DirkEddelbuettel, has there ever been thought or discussion towards that? It's not minor, I know.)

Comment: (To my first comment ... there are other advantages to using `apt` for R package maintenance, including dependency on external libraries that `install.package` cannot handle. I don't mean to downplay it in any sense.)